# Ember routing and application design

Tags: javascript, ember.js

**UPDATE**

I'll phrase my question differently because it's maybe more understandable this way : **I need to update 2 controller's model coming from a single server request, which is executed given a specific route like "/filter/xxxx" where xxxx is the filter to send in the request.**

- How to make the connexion between the route and the server request ?
- How to update the 2 controller's model when the request succeed ?

**ORIGINAL POST**

I've been looking for every tutorials about Ember I've found on internet, searched through the pretty well documented Ember's website, and a lot of StackOverflow questions, but never succeed to achieve exactly what I'm looking for...

Basically I've an application who consist of a Google Map showing some markers coming from the database and a filter section which let the user filter the markers.

When a user clicks on a filter, a request is sent to the server, and it answer back with a json response like so :

```
markers:
    0: {id: 6, title: "blablablabla", coords: {lat: x.xxxxxxxxxxxxx, lon: xx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx}}
    [...]
    14: {id: 20, title: "blablabla", coords: {lat: x.xxxxxxxxxxxxx, lon: xx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx}}
date_begin_label: "March 1, 2015"
date_end_label: "April 1, 2015"
selected: "last-month"
```

For the moment, I've created :

DateTimeSearch Template

```
<a href="#date-selection">{{ date_begin_label }} to {{ date_end_label }}</a>
<ul id="date-selection">
    <li><a href="/filter/today" {{ action 'fastFilterDate' 'today' }}>Today</a></li>
    <li><a href="/filter/yesterday" {{ action 'fastFilterDate' 'yesterday' }}>Yesterday</a></li>
    <li><a href="/filter/last-week" {{ action 'fastFilterDate' 'last-week' }}>Last Week</a></li>
    <li><a href="/filter/last-month" {{ action 'fastFilterDate' 'last-month'}}>Last Month</a></li>
    // also tried this
    {{#link-to 'map.fast-filter' 'today' tagName='li' href=no classNames='date-filter-today'}}
        {{#link-to 'map.fast-filter' 'today'}}Today{{/link-to}}
    {{/link-to}}
</ul>
```

Map Template

```
<header>
    {{ view App.DateTimeSearchView }}
</header>
<div id="map">&nbsp;</div>
```

MapView.js

```
App.MapView = Ember.View.extend({
    contentDidChange : function () {
        this.mapUpdate();
    }.observes("controller.content"),

    mapUpdate : function () {
        var markers = this.get("controller.model");
        // update the map
    },
});
```

Router.js

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource("map", { path : "/map" }, function () {
        this.route("fast-filter", { path : "/filter/:filter"});
    });
});
```

MapRoute.js

```
App.MapRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function (filter) {
        filter = filter.length ? filter : "today";
        var data = App.MapMarker.filter(filter);
        // don't know how to give data.date_begin_label, data.date_end_label
        // and data.selected to DateTimeSearchController...
        return data.markers;
    },

    actions : {
        fastFilterDate : function (filter) {
            var controller = this.get("controller");
            App.MapMarker.filter(filter).then(function (response) {
                controller.set("model", response);
                // don't know how to give data.date_begin_label, data.date_end_label
                // and data.selected to DateTimeSearchController...
            });
        }
    }
});
```

MapMarker.js

```
App.MapMarker = Ember.Object.extend({});
App.MapMarker.reopenClass({
    filter  : function (filter) {
        var path = "/api/filter/" + filter;
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            Ember.$.getJSON(path)
                .success(function (response) {
                    response.markers = response.markers.map(function (child) {
                        return App.MapMarker.create(child);
                    });
                    Ember.run(null, resolve, response);
                })
                .error(function (xhr, text_status, error) {
                    Ember.run(null, reject, error);
                })
            ;
        }, "MapMarker::filter::" + path);
    }
});
```

DateTimeSearchController.js

```
App.DateTimeSearchController = Em.Controller.extend({
    date_begin_label    : null,
    date_end_label      : null,
    selected            : null
});
```

DateTimeSearchView.js

```
App.DateTimeSearchView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName    : "datetime-search",
    tagName         : "section",
    idName          : "filter-section",

    date_begin_label    : Em.computed.alias("controller.date_begin_label"),
    date_end_label      : Em.computed.alias("controller.date_end_label"),
    selected            : Em.computed.alias("controller.selected")
});
```

**I need few things :**

- When the user click on the "today" filter, the URL must show : /map/filter/today
- Then the MapController's model get updated according to the choosen filter (like I'm actually doing with the "fastFilterDate" action)
- AND DateTimeSearchController's properties "date_begin_label", "date_end_label", "selected" also, knowing that these infos are coming from the same request as the MapController's model (don't know if I'm clear on this one).

**In my mind, I had this scenario :**

- Each filters would be a route, generated in the view with {{#link-to}} so when you click on it, the URL get updated and would show "/map/filter/xxxx"
- The application shows a little loader on the map template
- It sends a message to the MapController's model so it can be updated according to the choosen filter (never found out how to do this)
- When we get the response back, it updates the MapController's model with the markers, and update also the DateTimeSearchController with the few other properties (date_begin_label, date_end_label and selected).
- The MapView gets automatically updated with the new markers (I know how to do it)
- By default, when the application first load, the "today" filter is automatically set **WITHOUT** changing the URL (not showing /map/filter/today but only /map)

Of course, I want it to work also if someone enters directly the URL "http://xxxxxx.com/map/filter/xxx". I know I have to configure my server so it redirects to the location of my app, but the app must show the right filter.

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this, but I can't manage to find it... Maybe I should design it differently ?

**I DON'T WANT TO USE EMBER-DATA TO FILTER MY MARKERS, I REALLY WANT TO USE THE SERVER API**

Thanks!

Comment: The best way to do this would be to follow the Ember conventions and let your route provide the markers to a controller and use a component that takes those markers and displays them in the map.

Comment: That's not what I'm doing right now ?
The MapRoute provide the Markers to the MapController, but my question is more about how to handle interaction between the filters and the map.
I'm going to take a look at the components, sounds good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle The filters with query-params. That's what they are intended for. When query params are changed on the controller, the model refreshes. You wouldn't need and routes for the filters and could pass the filter as query param to the link-to helper.

See http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/query-params/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I'm doing it this way, I'm not sure I can handle the server response about the filter state (date_begin_label, date_end_label and selected), because my model only holds markers...
I need to update 2 models coming from 1 request who needs to be executed according to a route, maybe it's easier to understand said this way :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The filter state is changed on the client side and will remain like it is. You dont need to handle the response about filters and actually why does the server respond with any filters? As soon as one filter changes, the model is refeshed, the server should give you the filtered markers, the user can always see current filters he has set. If you explain more about the problem you would have with that solution maybe i can help.

Comment: Yeah I understand what you mean, but in certain conditions, I prefer handling the filters server-side. If I had to update 2 models with one request, how should I do ?

Comment: Use Ember.RSVP.hash in your routes model hook. 
`model: function(params) {
 return Em.RSVP.hash({
   markers: this.store.find('marker') or $.getJSON(....),
   filters: this.store.find('filter') or $.getJSON(....)....
                  });
}`
this should be fine. Access it in your controller with model.markers and model.filters. Or if you want your main model to be markers in controller, do:
`setupController: function(controller,model) {
   controller.set('model',model.markers);
   controller.set('filters', model.filters);
}`

Comment: Transform your results further in setupController if you have a custom structure and dont use ember-data.

Comment: If your models are in different controllers, use this.controllerFor('myFiltersModel').set('model', model.filters)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, It's been helping me a lot, I finally managed to make it work, the only problem left is that when I arrive on the map, I redirect directly to the first filter by a transitionTo, but, the model is not updated (the model function on the router is not called), instead, the query param I gave is taken as the current model (if I transitionTo("filter", { filter : "today"}); it's { filter : "today" } who's gonna end up being the model...).

Comment: (I don't know if I should tag your original answer as Accepted because It's your comments who actually helped me, how to do? Yeah I'm new here ;))

Comment: syntax should be: this.transitionTo('filter', {queryParams: {filter: 'today'}});
See http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/query-params/ 
Just mark my answer as correct and upvote the comment which helped you the most :)

Comment: Mmm, it doesn't work. When I'm using queryParams the redirect stop working. I think I'm going to post a second question about redirecting to a route while triggering the model function.
I read on the official documentation that using queryParams is the way to go, used with "refreshModel : true" but obviously this doesn't work.
Thank you very much for your answers (btw, I can't rate your comments, maybe cuz' I'm new).